# What are the options for monitoring web traffic by device

Tags: network-monitor

What are the options for monitoring web traffic by device. We are a small office currently using very basic router to connect to internet. The devices are computers, mac, ipad, mobile phones, etc. I want to monitor all those traffic and analyze the traffic by device. For example, if there are a lot of youtube traffic, I need to know which device was accessing youtube. Or if a suspicious website or IP destination has been repeatedly accessed, it is possible one of our devices has a trojan.

Many people on internet says there are plenty of solutions, yet without providing details or at least a link. If someone has hands-on experience or knowledge in doing configuration or installation of the solution, if you were me, what would you do?

As the end devices are in variety (Windows, Mac, Android, iPhone, even Linux) I guess it cannot be installed on each client devices. I need to install it on a server which communicate to the router/gateway. All network traffic should go through that server. The OS can be any. I have bit knowledge both Windows and Linux. Price would be from free to a couple thousands.

Comment: Thanks, integrated that with your question (and will clean up comments now). While waiting for answers: To my knowledge, there are some such projects for Raspberry Pi, so checking along the lines of "Raspi router" should bring up something. I cannot name specifics, though, as I didn't dig into that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Exact set up will depend on what router you are using - for my home network, I have a cheesy ISP provided barely usable thing... so my kids network goes through a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian acting as a router, DNS server, and DHCP server.  I control the amount of traffic available to them via `wondershaper` and I monitor which devices, etc. are using the bandwidth via `ntop`.

The `wondershaper` utility is in the apt archives, `ntop` is too but the site explaining it, etc. is https://www.ntop.org/